# Problems displaying all products on magento homepage

Tags: magento, view, product

i am having problems displaying all products on my magento homepage. I have added this code to my CMS - pages - design:

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

but had no luck. I have tried re-indexing my products and i have flushed the cache. Been at this for hours now looking for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Your root category id to block, so it will looks like:
{{block type="catalog/product_list" **category="2"** name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
and than change this category attribute "Is Anchor" to Yes.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Just tried exactly what you said and still no joy :( not sure whats going wrong here

Comment: the problem was i was writing the code in the design section of the cms and not the content. silly me!